# Pasted image and text in the editor doesn't work

Tags: images, editor

When I paste my image + text code in the "HTML" part and go to preview there should be my picture plus the link imbedded. It isn't working, the only thing showing is the text that I just pasted.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Hi. You can simply use the `Add media` button in the editor, and then paste your link in the `Insert from URL`. It's simple, and has more options.

Answer (score 0):

You must Add your image form Add media in text editor. After that click on image in text editor and then you fill find 5 option for image editing. There you can align image and edit image. Or it best practice to upload image from wordpress standard. The upload image will save in wp-content folder.